# Matplotlib matrix/image explicitly state axis values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would use imshow for this, so I will use it to describe my problem.
I have several matrices which I would like to plot on the same axis. Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,2],[0,1,2]])
x = np.array([0,1,2])
y = np.array([0,1])


a2 = np.array([[10,11,12],[10,11,12]])
x2 = np.array([10,11,12])
y2 = np.array([0,1])


plt.imshow(a,extent=[x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()])
plt.imshow(a2,extent=[x2.min(),x2.max(),y2.min(),y2.max()])

plt.show()
```

(With this code the first imshow is overwritten by the second)

The reason why I can't combine them into a single matrix with one set of x and y axes (by filling the gaps with zeros) is that the combined matrix would be huge and there are large spaces in between the strips.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear to me. Do you want to slice `a` and `a2` for relevant areas and display them in the same `axis` next to each other? Do you also want to axes to show correct ticks according to the positions in `a` and `a2` being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not overwritten, the axes limits are just reset to the extents of the last image each time.

Just call `plt.autoscale()`.

As a quick example of what you're seeing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1, data2 = np.random.random((2,10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data1, extent=[-10, 0, -10, 0])
ax.imshow(data2, extent=[10, 20, 10, 20])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, if we just call `autoscale`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1, data2 = np.random.random((2,10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data1, extent=[-10, 0, -10, 0])
ax.imshow(data2, extent=[10, 20, 10, 20])

ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

[image]